# Low efficiency of TF's bidirectional_dynamic_rnn using GPU

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I am using NVIDIA Tesla P40 to train a classification model. I used tensorflow's bidirectional_dynamic_rnn to build the bi-lstm network, and the training efficiency is so poor where only about 30% of computing resource are used, and the speed is even no faster than using the CPU with 45 logical cores. Could some help to give some advices fully using the GPU computing resource, or explain the reason?????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First hint: try to increase the `batch_size`. It will increase the amount of data to use in parallel, therefore decreasing the I/O time.

Note that, it will then require more GPU memory, so you have to tune it to avoid Out Of Memory errors.

Comment: a little bit help~~~

Comment: Hmmm what do you mean?